# Calculate what function is approximated with the Lagrange Polynomial

Tags: calculus, polynomials, numerical-methods, interpolation, lagrange-interpolation

I would like to find out what the sum estimates and prove that it estimates that function.
$$\sum_{j=0}^ml_j(x)*x_j^k=?$$
From the Lagrange interpolation polynomials we know that $$l_k(x) = \prod_{i=0}^m\frac{x-x_j}{x_m-x_j}$$

The sum estimates the $x^k$ as per my assumption, but how can I prove that this Lagrange interpolation polynomials estimates the $f(x)=x^k$ function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose you meant to write 
$$
l_{\,j} (x) = \prod\limits_{0\, \le \,i\, \ne \,j\, \le \,m} {{{x - x_{\,i} } \over {x_{\,j}  - x_{\,i} }}} \quad \left| {\;x_{\,0}  \ne x_{\,1}  \ne  \cdots  \ne x_{\,m} } \right.
$$
The $l_{\,j} (x)$ are polynomials in $x$, of degree $m$, which evaluate to $1$ in  ${x_{\,j} }$ and are null in the other points.
If you combine them with the values that a polynomial of degree $k <=m$ takes on $x_{\,0} ,x_{\,1} , \cdots ,x_{\,m} $ you will get that polynomial.

So $$
\quad x^{\,k}  = \sum\limits_{0\, \le \,j\, \le \,m} {l_{\,j} (x)\;x_{\,j} ^{\,k} } \quad 
$$
if $k<=m$

Comment: And how does this even solve it? I have to prove that the sum equals $x^k$. This is just like saying that the sum equals $x^k$ because it aproximates $x^k$. If you aproximatet with x1, x2, ... i's the actual value of the polynom

Comment: $x^k$ is a polynomial, of degree $k$. So its *interpolation* with Lagrange polynomials of equal or higher degree $m$ ($k <=m$) is not an *approximation* , it is a **full equality**.

Comment: You're missing my point. I asked HOW can I prove that the $\sum$ aproximates the function f(x) = $x^k$

Comment: Consider it as a this: $\sum$... = ?... I need to calculate the sum. I don't know what it would be, I guess it will be an $x^m$, But I **do not know** that the  $\sum$ equals that, I need to Calculate the sum and find out what is its value! Understand it now? :)

Comment: @Simply Me, yes I did understand you. Meanwhile, correct your definition of $l_{\,k} (x)$ which is not what "we know" as Lagrange poynomials.

Comment: Your answer was a good guide to finding the solution on my own. Thank you for help!

Comment: @ Simply Me  you are welcome.